# osmdroid map only view grid, can use osmdroid without external storage permission?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

My `osmdroid` map only displays an empty grid, why is it like that?[image]

I have searched in some of the same questions here and tried it but I cannot solve my problem.
I read `osmdroid` needs permission for sdcard / external storage.
Can I not use that? because my device doesn't support external storage or sdcard. 
This is my **code**

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));
        //Mapbox.getInstance(directmap.this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        IConfigurationProvider provider = Configuration.getInstance();
        File basePath = new File(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "osmdroid");
        //provider.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        provider.setOsmdroidBasePath(basePath);
        File tileCache = new File(provider.getOsmdroidBasePath().getAbsolutePath(), "tile");
        provider.setOsmdroidTileCache(tileCache);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directmap);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        final Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context1, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context1));
        Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapViewosm);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


       // mapView = (MapView) findViewById (R.id.mapViewosm);
       // button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        roadManager = new GraphHopperRoadManager(getString(R.string.apikey), true);
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        route.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mapView.onCre(savedInstanceState);
        //mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        startIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mark);
        //ambil lokasi pendonatur
        lat = -5.402213; //getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);,
        lng = 105.264113;//getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);

        setupOverlay();
        setupMap();
        addMarker();

    }
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));
        //Mapbox.getInstance(directmap.this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        IConfigurationProvider provider = Configuration.getInstance();
        File basePath = new File(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "osmdroid");
        //provider.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        provider.setOsmdroidBasePath(basePath);
        File tileCache = new File(provider.getOsmdroidBasePath().getAbsolutePath(), "tile");
        provider.setOsmdroidTileCache(tileCache);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directmap);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        final Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context1, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context1));
        Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapViewosm);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


       // mapView = (MapView) findViewById (R.id.mapViewosm);
       // button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        roadManager = new GraphHopperRoadManager(getString(R.string.apikey), true);
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        route.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mapView.onCre(savedInstanceState);
        //mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        startIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mark);
        //ambil lokasi pendonatur
        lat = -5.402213; //getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);,
        lng = 105.264113;//getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);

        setupOverlay();
        setupMap();
        addMarker();

    }
 private void setupMap() {
        // setting tile map
       // mapController = mapView.getController();
        BingMapTileSource.setBingKey(getString(R.string.bingkey));
        BingMapTileSource bingMap = new BingMapTileSource(null);
        bingMap.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_ROAD);


        // menambah overlay ke dalam map
        mapView.getOverlays().add(rotationGestureOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadNodeMarkers);

        //setting mapView
        mapView.setTileSource(bingMap);
        mapView.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
        mapView.setMinZoomLevel(1.0);
        mapView.setMaxZoomLevel(21.0);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.getZoomController().setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER);

        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(-5.402213, 105.264093));

    }

    private void addMarker() {
        Marker destMarker = new Marker(mapView);

        destPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        destMarker.setPosition(destPoint);
        destMarker.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
        destMarker.setSubDescription(getIntent().getStringExtra("username"));
        destMarker.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mark));

        mapView.getOverlays().add(destMarker);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
```

And this my **manifest**

```
   -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your device has no storage at all, not even internal storage for temporary files?

Comment: internal storage exists. but I don't know how to type the code. to change permissions from external storage to internal storage

Comment: Reading and writing to the internal sdcard also requires permissions `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. These terms are a little bit confusing.

Comment: emmm, do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

so you didn't mention which version of osmdroid or android that you are using, but without any mucking about with the config settings, it will default to application private storage and should just work as is. It should default to `/data/data/yourAppPackageName/osmdroid/`

if the default doesn't work (after resetting the config instance), then try to set the explicit path depicted above.